# Nativescript iOS app not running on device

Tags: nativescript

I'm encountering a strange issue and was hoping to get some insight. When I build my Nativescript app on a Mac, and open it in the iOS simulator, it works. When I "prepare" the iOS app and open it in xcode, and run it on a simulator, it works. When I run it to my plugged in device, it also works. But when I take that project to the Appstore, and download it from there, I only get the splash screen, and then the app exits. Can anyone please shed some light?

Comment: You will have to take it step by step, find where the problem is. I would say, try removing / commenting all your initial components, place them back one by one to see where the problem starts. Perhaps you could use Firebase Crashlytics, see if the crash report can give you some insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I managed to figure out what the issue is, so I hope this will help someone in future:

Even though I added "Push Notifications" as a Capability(Signing & Capabilities) in XCode, I had to add the "Background Modes" there as well, and then select "Remote Notifications".

This resolved the issue for me.